# how to share device between two or three machines

Tags: windows, osx, display, sharing

I have three machines at home two of them are windows one of them is mac os and i want to share the one keyboard one mouse and two screen with all of them how can i do it

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets like **howtos**, manuals, [multi-media content](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/935/185). It seems your question could fit on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), so you might wish to ask a mod to migrate it over – but not before having checked whether a similar question does already exist there: [Sharing keyboard and mouse between two boxes](https://superuser.com/q/770518/143340) seems to exactly match it :)

Comment: but synergy is not dealing with multiple screen i have a problem i want to share same two screen with all three machines for mac os i am using mac mini

Comment: Still doesn't match here – we are dealing with ***software*** recommendations only. As indicated, better check with [SU].

Comment: Are you looking for a solution such as teamviewer, in which you can control multiple computers from one computer?

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be installing VNC server+client packages on all 3 machines (like RealVNC or TightVNC) which would allow you to remotely access one from another.

Then play with the configurations to see which one matches your usage better (i.e. which machine should be driving the actual hw and access the other 2 machines via VNC). I'd start with the mac driving the hw :)

Won't be fast enough to play action games or watch videos, but it can be great for other stuff. Not sure if you'll be able to configure 2 remote displays - I never tried.

Of course, you may still need to hook up real hw once in a while if/when the machines get stuck at boot and don't make it to the point where the VNC server allows remote access.

There may be even faster similar sw out there, I didn't look as VNC worked decently enough for my usage.